# Select MS-Access Record On Right Click

Tags: vba, ms-access, right-click, continuous-forms

I have a form called "DetailedCalendar" with the default View "Continuous Forms".

The issue I'm having is that when I Right Click on a record, the context menu appears for the wrong record, in that the record was not selected.   I'm getting the ID of the record that was selected prior to the right click.

I saw a similar post called 'Get Current Record on Right-Click CommandBar Menu' but I'm not sure it was clear on what was trying to fix, and there was no clear answer.   I'm hoping my description will be a little more informative.

Can I make the right click select the record prior to displaying the shortcut menu?

I tried to use screen

```
Function LoadApplicationCommandBars() As String
    Dim lngReturn as long
    MenuChoice = "CalendarDetailContextMenu"
On Error Resume Next
    ' will cause error '5: Invalid procedure call or argument' if requested CommandBar does not exist
    Application.CommandBars(MenuChoice).Delete
On Error GoTo Routine_Err
    Set cbrNewMenu = Application.CommandBars.Add(MenuChoice, 5) ' 0=msoBarLeft, 1=msoBarTop, 2=msoBarRight, 3=msoBarBottom, 4=msoBarFloating, 5=msoBarPopup, 6=msoBarMenuBar
    Set mnuItem = cbrNewMenu.Controls.Add(msoControlButton)
        mnuItem.Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
        mnuItem.Caption = "Edit Row"
        mnuItem.OnAction = "=EditRow()"
        mnuItem.FaceId = 488
    strReturn = 0
Routine_End:
    LoadApplicationCommandBars = lngReturn
    Exit Function
Routine_Err:
    strReturn = Err.Number
    Resume Routine_End
End Function

'========================================================================
' from SHORT CUT menu
Public Function EditRow()
    MsgBox "LineID=" & Me![ID]
    'DoCmd.OpenForm "EditActivities", acNormal, "", "[ID]=" & ID
End Function
'========================================================================

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.ShortcutMenuBar = "CalendarDetailContextMenu"
End Sub
```

The closest I've gotten to finding a solution is to use the Form_MouseUp which provides X Y details of where the click occured, but I'm not sure how to use the coordinates to select the record.

```
Private Sub Form_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Debug.Print "Form_MouseUp " & Me![ID] & " x=" & X & " y=" & Y
End Sub
```

I fear there is no solution.  Can someone confirm?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Left click select record**, you cannot select with right click . unless you switch in windows settings the mouse buttons , but this effect all applications, and i don't think that you like the result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems the right click (the non-select button) will not select the record without serious intervention.

So, my best choice is to create a Button that covers the surface of my row, as all the information is read only anyway:

- I make the background transparent
- I remove the caption, although I may use the caption for other purposes in future, such as displaying a 'Cancelled' notification.
- I make the border transparent
- I set the Format for the Horizontal Anchor and the Vertical Anchor to 'Both'.

Now when I right click, it will activate the record with the Right Click and the shortcut menu still works.   I can't modify the details under the button, but that's ok for most uses of Continuous Forms where inline editing is not usually encouraged.

The other alternative is, to use the left-click and create a Form double click function.   Then I can bring up the options relating to the record on a separate form.